# Strange error when using KMDF MmCopyVirtualMemory() with PsGetProcessId()

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, kmdf

This code here is meant to be able to read kernel memory and theoretically should work.

```
bool read_kernel_memory(HANDLE pid, PVOID address, PVOID buffer, SIZE_T size) {
    if (!address || !buffer || !size)
        return false;

    SIZE_T bytes = 0;
    PEPROCESS process;
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(PsLookupProcessByProcessId(pid, &process))) {
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "proc lookup failed (rmode)");
        return false;
    }
    return MmCopyVirtualMemory(process, address, PsGetCurrentProcess(), buffer, size, KernelMode, &bytes) == STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

While I am writing, IntelliSense says that on the line that starts 'return MmCopyVirtualMemory(...'

`argument of type PEPROCESS is incompatible with parameter of type PEPROCESS`

(Thrown by the PsGetCurrenProcess() parameter)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I expected the code to copy the provide buffer in the pid and address provided and return `STATUS_SUCCESS`

I have tried initialising a PEPROCESS as a variable the line before and using that as the parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

I did in an included header
`#include ntifs.h`

and in the main file
`#include ntddk.h`

This causes redefinition errors and this error